# Initializing Structs in C++ and then retrieving by pass by reference

Tags: c++

I am trying to initializing structs in the following manner below, and then passing it by reference and then trying to retrieve the value. However, i get a random numbers back, which seems to suggest i dont have anything in that address. Why is this happening?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct newStruct {

int numberOne;
int numberTwo;
int numberThree;

};

newStruct initializer{
 1,2,3

};

 void printStruct(struct newStruct* inputNew) {
  printf("This is the output %d\n", inputNew->numberOne );
 printf("This is the second output %d\n", inputNew->numberTwo);
 printf("This is the third output %d\n", inputNew->numberThree);
}

int main() {

struct newStruct initializer;


printStruct(&initializer);
getchar();
}
```

Comment: Giving things the same name doesn’t make them the same thing.

Comment: Because you didn't initialize it.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22492318/how-to-refer-to-a-global-variable-which-has-the-same-name-as-a-local-variable-in).

Comment: newStruct initializer{
 1,2,3

};

Dosent this do the job?

Comment: The global variable (`::initializer`) is initialized, but not the local one (`initializer`).

Comment: Ah... How do i call this in the main function then?

Comment: global variable can be used as `::initializer`. Probably you don't need a local variable in this example.

Answer (score 2):

```
int main() {
    struct newStruct initializer;
```

Here you are defining a local, uninitialized variable of type `newStruct` called `initializer`; it has nothing to do with the global variable called `initializer` that you defined above, and, having the same name, the local actually hides the global (when you perform an unqualified name lookup).

To access the global variable just avoid defining a local with the same name.

```
int main() {
    printStruct(&initializer);
```

You can also refer to a hidden global by explicitly qualifying it with the scope resolution operator (as in, `::initializer`), but I don't think that's what you are after here.

---

By the way, this being C++ and not C you don't have to prefix `newStruct` with the `struct` keyword when you refer to the type name.